# Pin specific library versions in pyscript py-env

Tags: python, pyscript

How to specify the library version in pyscript's `py-venv` tag?

The docs are pretty clear on how to import libraries:

```
<py-env>
    - bokeh
    - numpy
    - paths:
      - /utils.py
</py-env>
```

But how do you pin particular library versions? Adding stuff like `numpy==1.21.6` seems to break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at some examples in the github repository of `pyscript`(see e.g. [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/pyscriptjs/examples/panel.html)) it should be done as follows:

```
<py-env>
 - bokeh
 - numpy
 - panel==0.13.1a2 # here is a specific version of a package
</py-env>
```

Comment: You're right, thanks FredMaster. Not sure why my initial attempt wasn't working. Maybe I was having some other problems with identation or whatever. Can confirm now that `            - numpy==1.22.3` works! I should've delved into the examples in the repo.

Comment: No worries. It could indeed be indentation. Pyscript is new to all of us.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with the <py-config> update.

Comment: whooops ran out of edit time. This doesn't seem to work with the move from <py-env> to <py-config> update.
packages = ["numpy==1.23.5"]
kicks a "can't find a pure python wheel..." error. 
packages = ["numpy"]
seems to load 1.24.2 which doesn't work with another package I'm using.